# how to insert table data from one user to another in different machines in mysql

Tags: mysql, insertion

I want to insert the data into one of the tables of a different user and a different database.

e.g.,

**First DB**

> ip:ip1
>
> user:user1
>
> b:db1

**Second DB**

> ip:ip2
>
> user:user2
>
> db:db2

So, I want to insert one of table's data of first DB into second DB.

Answer (score 1):

You should try with

> SELECT INTO OUTFILE

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select-into.html

and after that you can use

> LOAD DATA INFILE

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html

Answer (score 1):

You can try [SQLyog's](http://www.webyog.com) 'Copy Database to different host/Database' to copy from one MySQL server to another. Select the Database you want to copy and then Select Database -> Copy Database to different Host/DB to copy a database (with all or selected items of its table structure as well as the data) to another database (which may be located in another host).

Answer (score 0):

You have to do 2 `mysql_connect`, which return the connection.

Within your `mysql_query` where you insert the data you have to put your reference as second parameter

Like:

```
$db2 = mysql_connect('ip1', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
mysql_query ( "INSERT INTO *.....", $db2 )

$db1 = mysql_connect('ip2', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
mysql_query ( "INSERT INTO *.....", $db1 )
```

If your using Objects (which you should use) you just have to save the reference and pass it all queries executed. Then you can just make 2 DB objects with different IP's.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to attach remote tables using [FEDERATED](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/federated-storage-engine.html) storage engine, if your current version of MySQL is built with `--with-federated-storage-engine`

Use `SHOW ENGINES;` to see if the engine is supported in your installation.

Unfortunatelly, I have not yet tried that myself, and can not share any experience.